# Editing a Class with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So as weird as this sounds I have a full url as a class for some of my html elements. Obviously this doesn't work for css puposes. What I am looking to do is remove every thing except the page slug. Here is an example of what I have currently.

```
<li class="menu-item http://example.com/page-link/">some code</li>
```

What I would like to end up with as far as html goes is this:

```
<li class="menu-item page-link">some code</li>
```

I was thinking of using the .replace method to replace the "http://example.com/" with nothing but I am at a loss for removing the trailing slash and the beginning of the url. Here is my idea.

```
var strclass = $(li[class*=http://example.com/]).attr('class').match(/\bhttp://example.com/.+?\b/);
var newclass = strclass.replace("http://example.com/", "").replace("/", "")
```

Any help is appreciated. If I am going in the complete wrong direction with my code above please provides links to where you think I should be looking.

******I am trying something new and looking for more feedback!******

This is my new code I have compiled by combining some of your wonderful ideas.

```
if(li.hasClass('menu-item')) {
   var strclass = $('li.menu-item').attr('class');
   var newclass = strclass.split(" ")[1].split("/")[3];
   $(".menu-item").removeClass("http://example.com/" + strclass + "/").addClass(newclass);
}
```

The issue I am having with now is the third line inside of the if statement where I remove the old class with the full url and add the new class with only the page slug. If anyone has an idea of how to make that work or something else that would do the same thing please let me know. Thank you all for your hard work and prompt responses!

Comment: It does sound weird.  Why do you have URLs as classes?

Comment: is it always the same domain name used?

Comment: @Maulzal Because using the platform I am on (BigCommerce), One of the only ways to add a dynamically generated unique class to this list I am working on is by pulling either the category name or its URL. The names contain apostraphies and spaces so they don't work well as css classes. The URL on the other hand removes capitalization, symbols and replaces spaces with hyphens. All of which creates unique and css friendly classes if I can remove everything else.

Comment: @Stuart Yes the domain is always the same.

Comment: See my latest answer, it does exactly what you are attempting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does just what you are attempting:

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll("li.menu-item");
alert(items.length + " items with classes that need to be changed found.");

for(var i = 0 ; i < items.length; ++i){
   var classes = items[i].className.split(" ");
   items[i].className = classes[0] + " " + classes[1].split("/")[3];
   alert("New class attribute value is: " + items[i].className);
}
```

```css
.menu-item { font-family:Arial; font-size:1.5em; }
.page-link { background-color: red; }
.something {background-color: green;}
.go-somewhere {background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<li class="menu-item http://example.com/page-link/">some code</li>
<li class="menu-item http://example.com/something/">some code</li>
<li class="http://example.com/go-somewhere/">some code</li>
<li class="menu-item http://example.com/go-somewhere/">some code</li>
```

Comment: I think something like this would work but there is a huge list of items with classes that start with "http://example.com/" but have different page slugs at the end of it such as "http://example.com/page-link-2". How would I apply your method to all of them?

Comment: Wouldn't matter how the URL ends as long as what you are looking for comes after "http//example.com/". See my updated answer for an example.

Comment: So I am thinking to combine my original idea and yours

Comment: @TimFell See my latest update for just what you need. The `alert`s are only there for you to verify what's happening. Without them, it's just 4 lines of code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your dedicated help! I'll be trying this out this morning and will post when I get it to work.

Comment: Worked like a charm once I got the right classes set up and in the code. Thank you once again Scott!

Answer (score 0):

```
var strclass = "menu-item http://example.com/page-link/";
var newclass = strclass.replace("http\:\/\/.+\/(.+)\/", "$1");
```

Now I don't know if this would solve all your problems, but it sounds like you're just being too specific. Just make a more generic expression, and replace that part of the class string.

If you want something a bit less greedy, to only get the last folder

```
var newclass = strclass.replace("http\:\/\/.+\/([^\/]+)\/", "$1");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the slashes to build an array:

```
url = url.split("/");
```

Then get the slug which will be either the last or the second to last element in the array depending on if there is a trailing / or not.

```
if (url[url.length - 1]) {
  slug = url[url.length - 1];
} else {
  slug = url[url.length - 2];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use this regex with a replace: `/.*?([^/]+)\/?$/`

```js
$('li[class*="http://"]').each(function(){
  var pattern = new RegExp('^https?://');
  var classes = this.className.split(' ');
  for(var i = 0, len = classes.length; i < len; i++) {
    if(pattern.test(classes[i])) {
      classes[i] = classes[i].replace(/.*?([^/]+)\/?$/, '$1');
    }
  }
  this.className = classes.join(' ');
});
```

```css
.page-link {color: green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li class="menu-item http://example.com/page-link/">some code</li>
<li class="menu-item http://example.com/page-link/">some code</li>
<li class="menu-item http://example.com/page-link/">some code</li>
```

Note that my solution has a regex that tests against both http and https (excluding the `//example.com/whatever/` syntax and relative urls), but the jQuery selector only grabs the http linked list items.  You probably should create a class for this.  Something like `linked-list-item` or whatever.