# Can I pull a page slug as CSS class?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm wondering if there is a way to pull information from a URL (namely a page slug) and apply a class to an element based on the slug of the page.

```
http://www.example.com/pageslug/
```

Would it be possible to pull "pageslug" from the URL and insert it into an HTML element?

```
<div class="pageslug"></div>
```

Note: this is not a duplicate of [Editing a Class with Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36461245/editing-a-class-with-jquery)

I'm not looking to create classes based off of dynamically generated anchor tags that are on the page, I'm trying to create a class and assign it to an element based on the current page's URL structure.

Comment: What is a "pageslug"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Editing a Class with Jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36461245/editing-a-class-with-jquery)

Comment: You can use `window.location.pathname` to get the path which you can then parse. Do you want to do this on the client or on the server? If it's on the client, they may see a flash where the styles change or not at all if they have JavaScript disabled.

Comment: As in a file path to a page or the name of the page itself

Comment: This could be an "X Y Problem", please let us know, about what problem are you trying to solve by the aforementioned method.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it would need to happen server side or client side, but the element receiving the class name would be containing information relevant to the page itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".somediv").addClass(location.pathname.substr(1));
```

This should add the current pathname to an element of your choice. The pathname tends to have a beginning slash, so that's why the substr();

```
$(".somediv").addClass(location.pathname.replace(/\//g,''));
```

This will remove all the slashes from the pathname. This example does assume jquery. A vanilla example would be more like this.

```
document.querySelector("someelement").className += " "+location.pathname.replace(/\//g,'');
```

Comment: Note that this assumes there aren't other resources in the path.

Comment: Considering his use case, I am assuming that, yes.

Comment: The taxonomy is set up to only allow a single resource in the path.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another one

### [Demo](http://jsbin.com/dajuvaxobe/edit?html,css,js,output)

```
var dir = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1];
$('div').text('My class is: '+dir).addClass(dir);
```